# Find $1+\ln 2+\frac{1}{2} \ln^2 2+\frac{1}{6} \ln^3 2+\dotsb$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm stuck in finding the following sum

$$1+\ln 2+\frac{1}{2}\,\ln^2 2+\frac{1}{6}\,\ln^3 2+\dotsb$$

Need some hint.

Comment: Substitute $x = \ln 2$. Does the series now look familiar?

Comment: Was just about to suggest that... :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint:* Substituting $x = \ln 2$ gives
$$
 1 + \frac{x}{1!}  + \frac{x^2}{2!}  + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \ldots
$$
which is a well-known series for an even more well-known function.